# Align child div to bottom of parent div with dynamic height and width

Tags: height, width, alignment, parent

I don't know how to move ".buttons-box" to bottom of ".blog-item". I can set {position: relative;} for ".blog-item" and {position: absolute; bottom :0; right:0} for ".buttons-box", but it does not solve my problem, because change me width for ".buttons-box" and I need his width exactly as has ".content-box" and then I can't set width to 100%, because take width from relative parent, what is in this case "blog-item". I can't set specific width in pixels for "div.buttons-box" because is dynamic as ".content-box" and ".text". They have width according to image and this image can have different size in every single "blog-item".

**What i need:**

- moved div ".buttons-box" to bottom of ".blog-item"
- ".buttons-box" must have same width as ".content.box"
- ".buttons-box" must be under ".text" and must have placeholder for
  self, because if text will be too long, and if he had position
  abolute will be over text

Thank you!

**Image Sample:** ttp://i.stack.imgur.com/6WfUm.jpg

**JSFIDDLE Sample and Demonstration:** http://jsfiddle.net/yjdEk/

**Edit:**
My idea on JSFIDDLE: http://jsfiddle.net/RhShT/

- I created placeholder "buttons-box-placeholder" for buttons-box
- I set position relative for ".content-box" and postion absolute for
  ".buttons-box"

I need now some script for set width and height, but only from his parrents not global, becouse every single .blog-item can be different:

- .buttons-box width = .content-box width
- .content-box heigh = .blog-item height

Answer (score 0):

There is a CSS width property value called "inherit" which should make child's width equal to parent's.

Comment: yes you're right, but my parent div not have specific width in px, but has dynamic width.